# How to make sure that NSURLSession responses are received in same order as requests are made?

Tags: ios, swift

I make few NSURLSession requests in a loop. I'd like to store results from responses in the same order as tasks are created. But since completion handler runs in a separate thread it sometimes happens that the response to the second task gets received before the response to the first task.

How to make sure that I get responses in same order as tasks are being started?

```
var recivedData = [String]()

for index in 0 ... urlsAsString.count-1 {
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlsAsString[index])
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    // here I also set additional parameters (HTTPMethod, ...)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        responseData, response, error in

         // here I handle the response
         let result = ...
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
             self.recivedData.append("\(result)")   // save the result to array
         }
     }
     task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'd discourage behaviour that requires responses to be received in a specific order, you can collate the responses (regardless of the order they are received) into a known order.

The `receivedData` array should be initialised with a capacity that matches the number of requests that will be made:

```
var receivedData = [String](count: urlsAsString.count, repeatedValue: "")
```

Then when you receive the response, since you're in a block that has access to the `index` of the request you can add the response data directly into the index of the `receivedData` array:

```
receivedData[index] = result as (String)
```

The full code is as follows:

```
var receivedData = [String](count: urlsAsString.count, repeatedValue: "")

for index in 0 ... urlsAsString.count-1 {
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlsAsString[index])
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    // here I also set additional parameters (HTTPMethod, ...)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            responseData, response, error in

        // here I handle the response
        let result = ...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // Insert the result into the correct index
            receivedData[index] = result
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you know the exact number of http requests.

You can create an array to the size of `urls.count`, and then set the result in completion handler, corresponding to the index in each loop.

```
receivedData = [String](count: urls.count, repeatedValue: "No Data")
for (index,url) in enumerate(urls){
    let url = NSURL(string: url)!
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url){ data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            self.receivedData[index] = "error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            return
        }
        let result = ...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.recivedData[index] = "\(result)"
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, can not make sure the order of responses.
There are two workarounds for this:

1. Send the requests one after another, which means send the next request after the previous response is returned. You can use [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) to make your codes elegant. Or use the networking library I wrote [STNetTaskQueue](https://github.com/kevin0571/STNetTaskQueue), there is a STNetTaskChain which can handle the requests one after another.
2. Send the requests parallel(is what you are doing now), and use a NSDictionary to keep track on the request and response, after all requests is finished, combine the response in the original order.

Hope this helps!